# I am getting an error when I POST the form

Tags: post, django-forms

When i had the urls to other pages in the project level ulrs.py file, it all worked, but when i put the urls of other pages in the urls.py file in the app level urls.py file, the post method does not work.

**`#views.py file`**

```
    def index(request):

        return render(request,'read_write_app/index.html')



    def add_users(request):

        form = AddUserDetailsForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':

            form = AddUserDetailsForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                print('Validation Success')

                print('FIRST_NAME : '+form.cleaned_data['first_name'])

                print('MIDDLE_NAME : '+form.cleaned_data['midlle_name'])

                print('LAST_NAME : '+form.cleaned_data['last_name'])

                print('GENDER : '+form.cleaned_data['gender'])

                print('EMAIL : '+form.cleaned_data['email'])

                form.save(commit=True)

                return index(request)

            else:

                print('ERROR FORM INVALID')

        return render(request,'read_write_app/add_users.html',{'form':form})

    def view_users(request):

        user_list = User.objects.order_by('email')

        user_dict = {'users':user_list}

        return render(request,'read_write_app/view_users.html',context=user_dict)
```

**#app urls.py file**

```
app_name = 'read_write_app'



urlpatterns=[

    re_path(r'^view_users/$',views.view_users,name='view_users'),

    re_path(r'^add_users/$',views.add_users,name='add_users'),

]
```

## project urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [

    re_path(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    re_path(r'^read_write_app/',include('read_write_app.urls')),
```

## error

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/read_write_app/add_users/index.html

Using the URLconf defined in users_read_and_write.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
admin/
^read_write_app/ ^view_users/$ [name='view_users']
^read_write_app/ ^add_users/$ [name='add_users']
The current path, read_write_app/add_users/index.html, didn't match any of these.

## In the terminal

[30/Aug/2019 15:08:20] "GET /read_write_app/add_users/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2173
Not Found: /read_write_app/add_users/index.html
[30/Aug/2019 15:08:29] "POST /read_write_app/add_users/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2563

Comment: show full traceback

Comment: I have added new information from the browser and the terminal as well. See if it helps.

Comment: Try this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/read_write_app/add_users/

Comment: That works but it is not what i want